# Can't understand how Python interprets this 'or' operator

Tags: logical-operators

The way Python interprets the following syntax makes no sense to me (and I lost a good two hours debugging a code because of this!) :

Let's say you have the following code :

```
def returns_true():
    print('i\'ve been called!')
    return True

for val in [True, False]:
    print('val =', val)
    print(val or returns_true())
```

yielding the following output

```
val = True
True
val = False
i've been called!
True
```

Can someone explain why `returns_true()` only gets called when `val` is `False`? Shouldn't Python call the function in order to evaluate it's return value with the `or` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a "short-circuit" evaluation. Because `True or anything` must return `True`, the interpreter immediately returns `True` before evaluating the rest, which cannot change the outcome.

The `and` and `or` are short-circuit operators in Python as can be seen in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). The `or` operator will return immediately if the left hand side (LHS) is truish since the right hand side (RHS) cannot affect the result (`True or False == True or True == True`). The `and` operator will return immediately if the LHS is `False`, since the result is bound to be `False`

More information about short-circuit evaluation on [Wikipedia Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Right, that makes perfectly sense. Thank you!